# Closure: What are the most dangerous areas of London north of the River Thames [...]?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Why was [What are the most dangerous areas of London north of the River Thames?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81223/13759) by me closed, but not [What is the most dangerous area of Paris (or its suburbs) according to police statistics?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81146/13759)?

My question appears more specific as I included a map of a specific area.

Comment: I cast a reopen vote for you, hopefully this will lead to a happy ending that everyone agrees on.  But overall, expecting the site to behave with rigorous consistency is asking too much, it's not going to happen.

Comment: Your "specific" area is over 300 square miles!

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question, but at least the other person was asking about which areas to go to. By contrast, you were asking for an area to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

"According to police statistics" is a clear and precise definition. Your question didn't have a precise definition of what you consider 'dangerous' and therefore it was closed.

Comment: @pnuts I would simply take the absolute number of "assault crimes" per capita, regardless if those were rapes or murders.

Comment: @pnuts whatever the local police defines as "assault" is fine. Pickpockets, improper parking, money laundering, etc, does not count.

Comment: And yet it's been reopened, still without any precise definition of "dangerous." \*sigh\*